# hosting multiple application containers on a single server without conflicts

Tags: docker, server

i have a server that has a common dns and hosts multiple containers of different applications but the problem here for each domain name for an application, any app on the server can be accessed with the right port number. i have an internship management system and hospital management system on a single server with the respective domains; ims.ius.ca.com and hms.ius.ca.com where the common dns is "ius.ca.com". These two application have different port numbers 2301 and 2401 respectively. However, when a user keys hms.ius.ca.com:2301 the internship management system application is accessed instead of the hospital management. How do I resolve this conflict.

Comment: Why not use apps like nginx to forward requests to their appropriate ports? That way users don't have to use non-standard ports, and it's impossible to enter the wrong app with a different domain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Martheen The common solution for this problem is to have a reverse proxy in front of your applications (docker applications). You could use [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or [HAProxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts) as reverse proxy.